# Australia EOI - Are the "skill assessment" 10 points supposed to be added into the final point calculation on submission?

Tags: australia, pr

I received my skill assessment from ACS and lodged my EOI, but to my surprise the system calculated 10 points less than it was supposed to. I checked the calculation breakdown and noticed that I haven't received points for my skill assessment.

"Does the client have a suitable skills assessment from the relevant assessing authority?" is set to "Yes", "Name of assessing authority" is "Australian Computer Society Incorporated", "Date of skill assessment" is set to the date I received my PDF, and the reference number is set to the number I received from ACS, starting with "A-xxxxx".

All other points are attributed correctly, but the field for "Does the client have a suitable skills assessment" is missing from the calculation breakdown.

I tried different variations of date/reference combinations, for example leaving out the "A-" part, or using the date I submitted my application to ACS instead of when I received the PDF.

So my question is: Is this normal? Are the points excluded and only considered when actually applying for a visa? And if so, wouldn't that also affect whether I reach the cutoff level for invitation rounds?

Comment: Did the form ask for work experience dates?